# Why is the env directory called before echo?

Tags: environment-variables, c

I am looking at a program coded in C. The issue with this program relies on this line of code.

```
system("/usr/bin/env echo and now what?");
```

I understand that the system() just runs the command. But I am just not sure why it is like that.

Normally it would just be "echo and now what". But why is that "usr/bin/env" put in front of it? What exactly is that doing?

Comment: I am still not fully understanding it. I get what environmental variables are. A list of variables like used in programming that are used to hold data. But I don't understand why the calling of /usr/bin/env.

Comment: Or does calling the /usr/bin/env OR env before echo just say use the $PATH variable when looking for the "echo" command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/usr/bin/env` followed by the name of a program executes that program. It looks up the program name as an executable file in the directories configured by the `PATH` environment variable. It's a special case of the usage of `env`: `env` is followed by some environment variable assignments and then a program name and arguments — here there happens to be zero variable assignments.

`/usr/bin/env echo …` is equivalent to `/bin/echo …`, except that it doesn't hard-code the path to `echo` — depending on the system and on the value of `PATH`, it could be `/bin/echo`, `/usr/bin/echo`, `/usr/xpg4/echo`, `/usr/ucb/echo`, `/usr/local/bin/echo`, `/home/bob/bin/echo`, …

Almost every shell has an `echo` command built in. There may be differences in behavior between the shell builtin and the external command. In practice, there are variations between `echo` commands in two respects: what happens if the first argument begins with `-` (some versions of `echo` process a few options), and how a backslash is processed (some versions print it literally, others treat it as an escape character). So forcing a version of `echo` is useful occasionally, when you want to use these implementation-dependent behavior. In most cases it's better to use `printf` instead — `printf` can do everything that `echo` can do, and is portable except to antiques.

With the arguments passed in your sample code, the choice of an echo implementation doesn't matter. If there's a point to this madness, it would require a lot more context to figure out.

Comment: I am practicing some pentesting and this was part of a small C program on a Linux VM. The issue here is that I am able to edit the $PATH variable and add my own directory. So like /tmp. That way I can create my own "echo" command and then when the /usr/bin/env is used, it will go to the $PATH and see /tmp and look in there for my own echo. Which then my echo could be used to do what I need.

Answer (score 1):

> I understand that the system() just runs the command.

Correct.

> Normally it would just be "echo and now what".

Your are missing the last character.

> But why is that "/usr/bin/env" put in front of it?

That's the full path of the `env` command which is then the command executed instead of `echo`.

> What exactly is that doing?

It prevents the `echo` builtin to be executed by the shell spawned by the `system` `libc` function so the `echo` executable first found in the PATH is used instead. Depending on the respective `echo` implementations, the behavior might be different although I don't see here anything particular. In both cases, "and now what?" should be printed unless you are unlucky and have a file which five letters name starts with "what", like for example "whatz" in your current directory. If it is the case, what would be printed is:

> and now whatz